# Efficiently reusing code common to multiple implementations of a polymorphic method

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have a shape. Shape has a circle, triangle, square.

```
class interface Shape(){
   print();
   sort(); 
}
```

If `circle`, `triangle`, and `square` extend `shape`, and the code for `sort()` is nearly identical for all shapes, how can I use `sort()` without adding the body implementation in circle, triangle and square?

I can have a concrete implementation in `shape` but I was always told not to do that.

Comment: if the method is the same for all shapes, make the Shape an abstract class and write the concrete definition of the method there. If not, use it as an interface and override the method in each class.

Comment: I've cleaned up your question as best I can, but it still needs help. Please edit in some actual code; there are several syntax errors in the code you've provided.  shape can't be both a class and an interface, and the parentheses shouldn't be there either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `abstract class` which allows you **either** to **implement** `sort()` method (`class` behavior) and **define** `print()` method (`interface` behavior):

```
public abstract class AbstractShape
{
    public abstract void print();

    public void sort(AbstractShape[] shapes) {
        // make your own implementation -> sort shapes
    }
}

public class Circle extends AbstractShape
{
    @Override public void print() {
        System.out.println("I'm a circle");
    }
}

public class Triangle extends AbstractShape
{
    @Override public void print() {
        System.out.println("I'm a triangle");
    }
}

public class Square extends AbstractShape
{
   @Override public void print() {
        System.out.println("I'm a square");
    }
}
```

Comment: is the @Overide needed?

Comment: `@Override` indicates that a method declaration is intended to override a method declaration in a supertype. If a method is annotated with this **annotation**, compilers are required to generate an error message unless at least one of the following conditions hold:
1 - the method does override or implement a method declared in a supertype;
2 - the method has a signature that is override-equivalent to that of any public method declared in Object.

Comment: If the `@Override` isn't specified, the method declared in the subclasses always override the method declared in the superclass, but with this annotation you can specify an additional behavior.

Answer (score 0):

How would you define the order of shapes of different types?

If it's an arbitrary order such as - Circles first, then Triangles and finally Squares - you comparison method would have to know all of those types.

If you define the order based on some properties shared by all the shapes, such as area, you can implement the comparison method in your Shape class without it knowing any of the sub-classes.

BTW, if your `sort()` method is supposed to sort a Collection of Shapes, you don't need it. Use Collections.sort and implement `Comparator<Shape>` or `Comparable<Shape>`.